# Multiple open sql connections

Tags: nhibernate

On a single page load I see several connections open. Although there are a at least 20 calls to the database, I see around 8 connections open before slowly dropping off. Each call is wrapped in a using statement, uses OpenStatelessSession and a singleton factory for nhibernate object. Shouldn't I only see a single connection open or is this normal behavior? I'm concerned because this is a high traffic site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each session always runs on a separate connection. If your site is exhausting the connection pool under load, you can switch to a session-per-request architecture, but that will of course consume more memory and CPU cycles due to the increased size of the first level cache.